# wysihtml5 not working properly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wysihtml5, bootstrap-wysihtml5

I'm in trouble with `wysihtml5` editor (for bootstrap). It takes only three lines and eliminated other lines. When I gave 10 lines in the editor. It takes only three lines. So that three lines only saved.

In view(`_form.html.erb`):

```
<%= simple_form_for @announcement, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %><br/>
  <%= f.input :description, as: 'text', :input_html =>{:rows => '25', :cols => '25', :class => 'input wysihtml5' } %>
  <div class="input string optional"><label class="string optional control-label" for="school_school_name">Upload Logo</label> 
    <%= f.fields_for :pictures do |i| %>
      <%= i.file_field :avatar %>
    <% end %></div><br/>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                announcements_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The model:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper
class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name,  :pictures_attributes


  #association
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: :true


   #before_save :strip_html  

end
```

The controller:

```
class AnnouncementsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /announcements
  # GET /announcements.json
  def index
    @announcements = Announcement.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @announcements }
    end
  end

  # GET /announcements/1
  # GET /announcements/1.json
  def show
    @announcement = Announcement.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @announcement }
    end
  end

  # GET /announcements/new
  # GET /announcements/new.json
  def new
    @announcement = Announcement.new
    @announcement.pictures.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @announcement }
    end
  end

  # GET /announcements/1/edit
  def edit
    @announcement = Announcement.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /announcements
  # POST /announcements.json
  def create
    @announcement = Announcement.new(params[:announcement])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @announcement.save
        format.html { redirect_to @announcement, notice: 'Announcement was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @announcement, status: :created, location: @announcement }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @announcement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /announcements/1
  # PUT /announcements/1.json
  def update
    @announcement = Announcement.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @announcement.update_attributes(params[:announcement])
        format.html { redirect_to @announcement, notice: 'Announcement was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @announcement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /announcements/1
  # DELETE /announcements/1.json
  def destroy
    @announcement = Announcement.find(params[:id])
    @announcement.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to announcements_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

JS script to run `wysihtml5`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wysihtml5").wysihtml5();    
})
```

Comment: try look into the param[:description] that pass through your web server to check whether the value is correct.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is because your attribute is setup as a wrong type in the database. You probably have it as string rather than text, so it's automatically truncating it.